# Python path in command prompt

Tags: python, command-prompt

I had Python3 installed on my computer after Python2. Then I executed "python" in command prompt, Python3 showed up.
How does the command prompt find Python without specifying the path?
Can I switch it back to Python2 without reinstalling?

Comment: What OS do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on windows you need the python27 to be first in your PATH enviroment variable

```
PATH=c:\python27;otherstuff...;c:\python35;...;
```

or just write

```
py -2
```

To start python2

Comment: Please note that there is no mention of Python2.7 in OPs post, nor does python have to be installed in the root of drive C.